# Reading Data from an array in a separate class

Tags: c#, arrays

I am trying to read data from an array I have in one class from another array.

The first class:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;

namespace Munchkin
{
    class GameInfo
    {
        public static void CardInfo()
        {

            //Array for Monster Cards {Name, HP}
            string[,] monsterCards = new string[,] { { "Bob", "500" }, { "Billy", "600" }, { "Joe", "700" }, { "Frank", "750" }, { "BillyBob", "850" } };
            //for (int i = 0; i < ((monsterCards.Length) / 2); i++)
            //{
            //  WriteLine("Monster name {0}, Health Points {1}", monsterCards[i, 0], monsterCards[i, 1]);
            //}
        }

    }
}
```

My other class is:

```
using System;
using static System.Console;
using System.Threading;


namespace Munchkin
{
    class Battle
    {
        public static bool Big;
        public static void BigChance()
        {
            int chance;
            Random rand1 = new Random();
            chance = rand1.Next(1, 101);

            if(chance > 95)
            {
                Big = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Big = false;
            }
        }

        public static void BattleStart()
        {
            BigChance();
            GameInfo CardInfo = new GameInfo();
            Random pickMonster = new Random();
            int monster = pickMonster.Next(0, (monsterCards.Length) / 2);
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried various things, including changing permissions, and I can't seem to be able to read the data or pass the data in any way.

Answer (score 0):

The symbol `monsterCards` is declared as a local variable and is inaccessible anywhere outside the local (method) scope.

You could move the variable to class scope, like this:

```
class GameInfo
{
    private string[,] monsterCards = new string[,] { { "Bob", "500" }, { etc...

    public static void CardInfo()
    {
        //Stuff
    }
}
```

Then add a property to make it available outside the class:

```
class GameInfo
{
    ....
    public string[,] GetMonsterCards()
    {
        return this.monsterCards;
    }
}
```

And now you can read it from the other class:

```
 public static void BattleStart()
 {
     BigChance();
     GameInfo CardInfo = new GameInfo();
     Random pickMonster = new Random();
     int monster = pickMonster.Next(0, (CardInfo.GetMonsterCards().Length) / 2);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the life of me I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the array of the `GameInfo` class to be accessible to other classes, make it a public property: `public` property:

```
class GameInfo
{
    public string[,] monsterCards;

    public static void GameInfo()
    {
        //Array for Monster Cards {Name, HP}
        monsterCards = new string[,] 
        { 
            { "Bob", "500" }, { "Billy", "600" }, { "Joe", "700" }, 
            { "Frank", "750" }, { "BillyBob", "850" } 
        };
    }           
}
```

Then in your other method you can access it like:

```
public static void BattleStart()
{
    BigChance();
    GameInfo CardInfo = new GameInfo();
    Random pickMonster = new Random();
    int monster = pickMonster.Next(0, (CardInfo.monsterCards.Length) / 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something more like this:

```
class GameInfo
{
    public Dictionary<string, int> MonsterCards { get; private set; }
    public GameInfo()
    {
        this.MonsterCards = new Dictionary<string, int>()
        {
            { "Bob", 500 }, { "Billy", 600 }, { "Joe", 700 }, { "Frank", 750 }, { "BillyBob", 850 }
        };
    }
}

class Battle
{
    private Random _random = new Random();
    public bool Big { get; private set; }
    public void BigChance()
    {
        this.Big = _random.NextDouble() >= 0.95;
    }

    public void BattleStart()
    {
        this.BigChance();
        GameInfo gameInfo = new GameInfo();
        int monster = _random.Next(0, (gameInfo.MonsterCards.Count) / 2);
    }
}
```